# Hide bcc field in draft email display

Tags: vba, outlook, visibility, ribbon, bcc

I'm trying to hide the Bcc field in an email being drafted in Outlook 2010.

I'm using code to add an email address to Bcc which shows the field. I want the real-estate on the screen back.

Here's what I have so far (in ThisOutlookSession):

```vb
Sub add_bcc_to_cur_email()
    Dim cur_msg As MailItem
    Set cur_msg = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    cur_msg.BCC = "first.last@domain.com" 'this works correctly
    cur_msg.GetInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "Bcc" 'this does nothing
End Sub
```

I was thinking there was a way to control the visibility of the Bcc field directly. I found [this](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-35958.html) -- The second post seemed to have a solution, but that was for 2003.

I thought I could try to launch the Bcc item in the Ribbon: Options > Show Fields > Bcc.
I googled and came up with [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d7555e82-00ed-44b6-bae1-0dfbfd50ca58/outlook-2010-vba-macro-to-execute-a-ribbon-button?forum=outlookdev). The thread seemed to be inconclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me in 2010

```
cur_msg.GetInspector.Commandbars("Menu Bar").Controls("View").controls("Bcc Field").execute
```

Comment: wont over post your answer with another answer but this works as well  cur_msg.GetInspector.CommandBars.FindControl(, 1860, , False).Execute

Comment: Thank you, Dick. I copied your solution, which appears to be exactly what was in the second link that I posted, and this time it worked. I must have copied from the link wrongly the first time or something. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you as well, Sorceri! I will stick to Dick's solution for now, since it's easier to parse, but I appreciate the additional knowledge :)