# Outlook 2007 - hide From field using VB

Tags: vb.net, vba, vbscript, outlook

I have a VB script to automate some functions when replying to messages sent to a shared mailbox.

One feature is that replies are sent from the user's mailbox and not from the shared mailbox account.

**I need to be able to hide the From field in replies.** It is currently displayed in the Reply window.

I have the following code, which doesn't work.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

I am using Outlook 2007.

```
oMail.GetInspector.CommandBars("Options").Controls("Fields").Controls("From Field").Execute
```

*Where oMail is defined as Outlook.MailItem*

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop a custom form in Outlook. See [Microsoft Outlook Custom Forms](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=35) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, but I'm quite sure it can be done using VB script without resorting to custom forms.

See here, for example: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911538/want-to-hide-bcc-field-in-outlook-2010-email-using-vba

I tried the following:
`cur_msg.GetInspector.CommandBars.FindControl(, 1867, , False).Execute`

(1867 is the control code for the From field)

But this doesn't seem to work... is there something I'm doing wrong?